# Validations in IE11 for multiple select breaks

Tags: javascript, validation, angular

I am using `ReactiveForms` in my application.  The validators work as expected in Chrome but not in IE11.  Unfortunately, I couldn't get the Plunkr to work in IE11 and was informed on the *Angular2 Gitter* that **Angular2 Plunkers don't work in IE11**, but perhaps my issue is reproducible in Edge (I don't have access to Edge at the moment).

I kept the example as simple as possible.  The problem occurs when there is a multiple select in IE11.  I am setting the `required` validator and `minLength(1)` validator on the `FormControl`.  When I click one of the options, and then click outside of the selector, the validation error pops up.  This is not the expected outcome.  It's behaving like the selected item is being deselected on a blur event.

http://plnkr.co/edit/eZfbnzDz3jx9NcnaO51R?p=preview

**Form class**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'multiple-selector-form',
  templateUrl: './src/multiples-selector-form.html'
})

export class MultipleSelectorForm {
  availableSelectItems: Array<any> = [
    {type: 'H', display: 'High'},
    {type: 'L', display: 'Low'}
  ];
  multipleSelectorForm: FormGroup;
  selectItemsCtrlRef: FormControl;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.multipleSelectorForm = this.fb.group({
      selectItems: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]]
    });
  }
}
```

**Form html**

```
<form [formGroup]="multipleSelectorForm">
  <div>
    <label for="multipleItemSelector">Multiple Items Selector</label>
    <select formControlName="selectItems" multiple="multiple">
      <option *ngFor="let item of availableSelectItems" [ngValue]="item">
        {{item.display}}
      </option>
    </select>
    <div *ngIf="selectItemsCtrlRef?.invalid && (selectItemsCtrlRef?.dirty || selectItemsCtrlRef?.touched) && (selectItemsCtrlRef?.errors?.required || selectItemsCtrlRef?.errors?.minLength)">
      Selection is required
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Again, this is not reproducible in Chrome, but I put the Plunkr out there in case it is reproducible in Edge.  I don't have access to Edge at this moment, but will later on in the day.

To summarize, I'd like the validator behave as expected, where it doesn't display after selecting an item in the selector and then clicking outside of it.

**UPDATE 1**

I was wrong about the behavior of how clicking interacts with the multiselect for Angular 2 ReactiveForms in IE11.  The click event is registered whenever clicking an element in the multiselect; this is signaled by highlighting that element with a gray background.  However, the element isn't actually being selected.  This usually takes multiple clicks and is signified with a blue background.  I'm not 100% what's going on, but I'm working on a code fix, probably in `main.ts` since this is occurring for all multiselects in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this turned out to be a really weird defect in the application without much of a code fix besides adding a shim to the `index.html` for IE.

In the app, we capture IFrame mousedown events to close any dropdowns.  It turned out that we were trying to instantiate a new `Event` to dispatch on `document` and IE doesn't support the `Event` constructor.